# What is the use of creating bridges in EMS

Tags: tibco

I am aware of how to create bridges in EMS 
But 
What is the use of creating bridges in EMS...instead of directly specifying the name of the destination queue or subscriber ..

Is it for reliability purposes  ?

Kindly explain me with the "WHY" part of usings bridges in EMS with suitable examples 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see many "why" for EMS bridges.

Of the top of my head:

- Create a topic out of an existing (and currently used) queue
- By bridging a topic to a queue, make a more versatile durable subscriber (more options)
- The "Topic to queue" pipe and filter pattern: Imagine all your (EAI) modules. All shall read from a queue, and write to a topic. Connectivity is not done in BW (or another writing application), but directly in the EMS configuration with bridges. A message from module A needs to be read by module B and module C ? Simply create 2 bridges from the module A outbound topic to module B and C inbound queues. Done ! Now the code does NOT have to be edited to adjust routing, and every module "stack" is well maintained by the inbound queues. (even if the module is off-line)
- Bridges are useful with routes (multiple EMS instances), because of message selector feature (a JMS feature, not EMS, but very helpful with bridges). If a message in one queue needs to be sent to ONE out of 3 different EMS instances, based on a JMS property... then use a bridge with a message selector. No need for code.

I got more ;-) Seriously, it is a cool feature of EMS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! Where can i find useful tibco tutorials other than  its documentation

Comment: Look here : https://tibbr.tibcommunity.com/tibbr/#!/explore/search?q=ems tutorial

Comment: Also look at the samples, installed with the product. Great stuff there.

Comment: Here are my articles on the subject : http://www.integist.info/2014/07/11/tibco-ems-on-centos-vm/

Comment: article 2 : http://www.integist.info/2015/03/19/tibco-ems-8-fault-tolerance-nfs4/

Comment: And finally... if you don't find readings on the specific subject you wish to allow you to leverage EMS... try to make a match between the classic EI patterns and the product doc. EIP : http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/